# Trying to import SQL File with command

Tags: mysql, command-line-interface

I want to import a sql file to a database. I work on Windows 10 and I want to use the commands lines.

I tried this :

```
C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\bin\mysql -u {username} -p{password} db_test < F:\BDD\_databasetest\test.sql
```

But I have an error : "C:\Program not recognized"

So I tried to go by step :

```
cd C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\bin
mysql -u {username} -p{password}
mysql db_test < F:\BDD\_databasetest\test.sql
```

But at the third command, I have this error :

ERROR:
Unknown command '\B'.
ERROR:
Unknown command '_'.
Outfile disabled.

For the command "mysql db_test < F:\BDD_databasetest\test.sql" I'm not sure about the "mysql" part so I tried both, with the same error. I tried to double the \ in the path, and I tried to used '' and "" for the path, without succes.

PS : english is not my native language. I clarifications are needed, don't hesitate.

Comment: put the path in double-quotes, that may help. "C:\Progam Files...."

Comment: it worked ! thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So as the OP confirmed, double-quoting the Windows path helped:
`"C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\bin\mysql" -u {username} -p{password} db_test < F:\BDD\_databasetest\test.sql`

The error message 'error : "C:\Program not recognized"' suggest that it is not a  mysql-related issue.

Answer (score 0):

with the first mysql commad you can't to the database so the mnexe must be a sql command

For both options the database has to exit already, if in the sql is no CREATE DATABASE ...

use

```
mysql -u root -p db_test < D:\BDD\_databasetest\test.sql
```

or

```
mysql -u {username} -p{password}

mysql> use db_test ;

mysql> source D:/BDD/_databasetest/test.sql;
```

Note in the last command the `/` instad of `\`